# Iterating through a firebase node syntax error?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Here is my code to iterate and add up values on a certain node

```
exports.onAddToCart = functions.database.ref('/users/user_cart/{uid}').onWrite((change, context) =>{

const item = change.after.val();
const userId = context.params.uid;
const servicePath = admin.database().ref('/services/' + item);

return servicePath.once('value').then(snapshot =>{

    if(!snapshot.hasChildren()) {

        return null;

    }

    let totalPrice = 0;

    snapshot.forEach(function(child){

        totalPrice += child.val().price;

    });

    return admin.database().ref('/users/user_cart/' + userId + '/total').set(totalPrice);

});

});
```

Unfortunately, I cannot get this to work even after following the documentation letter for letter (I guess?). I receive this error...

[image]

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying your function needs to return a boolean.  Right now it's returning nothing:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(child){
    totalPrice += child.val().price;
});
```

The API docs for [`forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) say that the action handler can return true to cancel the iteration, so you probably want to return false if you don't want to cancel:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(child){
    totalPrice += child.val().price;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It didn't explicitly say that, but I think that's it. Thanks :-D

Comment: The error message is saying this.  Compare given function types in the message, and you'll see that it wants a boolean where you're giving a void.  You can also command-click into forEach to see what it expects in the type mapping files.

Comment: I meant the firebase documentation didn't explicitly state that. Sorry for the confusion. I just noticed you're the guy from the firebase cloud functions videos! :-D Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the API docs are written with JavaScript in mind. JS is not going to check the types of things, and void automatically converts to a "falsy" value when checked with a conditional.  This could be improved for TypeScript.  Hope you're finding the videos helpful!